# Разовое выполнение функции

Tags: javascript, html

Интересует такой момент, как можно сделать что бы функция JS по нажатию на button выполнялась только 1 раз, т.е если еще раз повторить клик, что бы она не запускалась еще раз заново. Т.е проблема в том, что когда на странице нажимаешь на "START" функция работает как надо, но когда нажимаешь на "STOP" она запускается снова с самого начала, а не прекращает свою работу. Спасибо заранее. Код:

```js
function ex(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('firstArrow');
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('secondArrow');
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('thirdArrow');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.checkmark-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.checkmark-circle .background {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark.draw:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-name: checkmark;
  -moz-animation-name: checkmark;
  animation-name: checkmark;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 25px;
  width: 27.5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5px !important;
  content: '';
  left: 3px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.w3-button {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button class="w3-button w3-deep-orange" id="btn">Deep Orange</button></p>

<div class="checkmark-circle" id="firstArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет `removeEventListener`, но для этого надо функцию обработчик события вынести в отдельную функцию, тоесть нужно чтобы у нее было имя. Алгоритм в общем прост, при клике удаляем обработчик и выполняем нужный код, примерно так :

```js
var a = document.getElementById('testBtn');
a.addEventListener('click', clicker);

function clicker() {
  document.getElementById('testBtn').removeEventListener('click', clicker);
  console.log('click');
};
```

```html
<button id="testBtn"> click me once </button>
```

Или же можно сделать какойто флаг, по которому смотреть надо выполнять тело функции или нет, например :

```js
var a = document.getElementById('testBtn');
a.addEventListener('click', clicker);
var flag = true;    

function clicker() {
  if(flag){
      console.log('click');
      flag = false;
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="testBtn"> click me once </button>
```

в первом варианте возобновить выполнение обработчика можно с помощью `addEventListener`, тоесть просто повторно его прицепить, во втором варианте можно просто обновить значение переменной `flag`